# Can't talk to Express back-end from EC2 Ubuntu server

Tags: nginx, express, proxy, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 server and I know that I can curl what I expect to see from a little ExpressJS server there. What I want to do is proxy that service through nginx.

I have ensured that the security group allows all TCP connections internally.

The nginx config looks like this and the final location is just static stuff:

```
server {
    server_name ec2-54-197-241-212.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /home/ubuntu/bishbashbosh/htdocs;
    index index.html;

    location @express {
        internal;        
        proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:9999;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /maintenance.html $uri @express;
    } 

    location ~* /[icons|fonts|swf|resources]/.* {
        expires 30d;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            return 404;
        }
    }

}
```

When I request anything that isn't static from using a browser it just times out. Have I done something terribly silly?